# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official' error when running Tensorflow Official MNIST Model in a Colaboratory notebook?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist, google-colaboratory

I downloaded the official Tensorflow MNIST models (from https://github.com/tensorflow/models), and I have run them successfully in an Anaconda Prompt. However, I would like to run them through a Colaboratory Notebook but I am having trouble getting the script to recognize the "official" directory that contains all the necessary files to import. I have tried to add the "official" directory to my google drive, and also to the python installation directory in my hard drive without success.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What did you try, and what is the error you encountered? Can you share a notebook that reproduces the problem?

Comment: The notebook can be found here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13Gl9l-xnIL4OeNgd-Wqrb2bMcG10NUF1

Comment: I have been unable to import the "dataset" script from official.mnist. I have tried to add the directory containing all of the official model files to my PYTHONPATH variable, I have installed all the dependencies, and I have tried uploading the official model files to my google drive (I was hoping that google drive would act as a local directory that the colaboratory notebook would be able to access directly).